# installing RQuantLib in R -- MAC OSX Mavericks

Tags: r, macos, package, quantlib

I have been trying to install `RQuantLib` in RStudio but want to know if someone found a workaround to get it up and running in MAC OSX Mavericks:

I have downloaded the `OS X Snow Leopard binaries` (because Mavericks are not available) from:
[CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RQuantLib/index.html)

When I run the following code, it says I have installed the package:

```
install.packages("/Volumes/3TB/R/RQuantLib_0.3.12.tgz", repos = NULL, type='source')
* installing *binary* package ‘RQuantLib’ ...
* DONE (RQuantLib)
```

However, when i try to load it, it fails:

```
library("RQuantLib")
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'RQuantLib', details:
  call: if (is.character(qc) && nchar(qc) > 1) {
  error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
running command 'bash -c 'type -p quantlib-config' 2>/dev/null' had status 1 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RQuantLib’
```

Can someone please help me out ?

Session info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] blotter_0.8.19   grid_3.1.2       lattice_0.20-29  quantstrat_0.8.2 Rcpp_0.11.4      tools_3.1.2      zoo_1.7-11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first install [QuantLib](http://quantlib.org/install.shtml) on your computer in order to use `RQuantLib`.